# Wrap code in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For long lines of C# code in a ASP.NET MVC Razor view, how can you wrap the code onto the next line?  If I add a carriage return, it renders the code as HTML.

**Edit**: Here's an example of the code I would like to wrap. In the last line, the added method calls start to run off the screen and I'd like to carry something like `.WithAjax(true)` to the next line.

```
@Html.Grid(stuff).Columns(columns =>
{
    //stuff
}).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters().WithPaging(WebSettings.DefaultPageSize)
  .WithAjax(true).Exportable(true)
```

Comment: It seems that if you add a CR within round brackets you're ok, but not if you wrap before a period

Comment: Can you show what's your desired result with an example?

Comment: I've edited with an example

Comment: OK. Check my answer.

Comment: Put them in your controller is the correct answer here. Your views shouldn't contain any code blocks and certainly not large code blocks.

Comment: @Liam The `@Html.Grid` is a UI helper and it has to be placed in the view.

Comment: A good reason not to use it then

Comment: @Liam But HTML Helpers, helps in the rapid development of a view and they are used in View to render HTML content.

Comment: I don't really think this is the place for this conversation, but they also bypass many of the underlying concepts of MVC (the pattern), are inflexible, inefficient and generally clunky to use. It's like webforms never died...

Comment: How data is displayed is the job of the view, not the controller, hence the introduction of a logic-capable tech in Razor.  But you're right, this is not the right place for this conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@()` like this:

```
@(Html.Grid(stuff).Columns(columns =>
{
//stuff
}).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
  .WithPaging(WebSettings.DefaultPageSize)
  .WithAjax(true).Exportable(true))
```

This is called [Explicit Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor).

Answer (score 2):

You can enclose a "Razor code block" using the `@{ }` syntax. The contents will not be rendered, but variables declared inside are accessible by the rest of the page.

```
@{
    string longMessage = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur " +
        /* these linebreaks will not be part of the string variable */ +
        "adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna.";
} 

@* Now render the string variable declared in the code block *@
<p>@longMessage</p>
```

See [Razor syntax for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor).

**Edit**

For your concrete code:

```
 @{
    // assign the IHtmlString created by the HTML Helper to a variable
    var grid = Html.Grid(stuff).Columns(columns =>
        {
          //stuff
        }).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
        .WithPaging(WebSettings.DefaultPageSize)
        .WithAjax(true).Exportable(true));
 }

@* now render the variable content *@
@grid
```

Comment: I can confirm the braces approach doesn't work with my example - it expects a return value

Comment: Should still work if you assign the output to a variable and then render this variable, see my edit.